# How to import a function or its return value from typescript (.ts) to javascript (.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, angular-services

I have a typescript file

**a.component.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class DataService {
  constructor(private httpCLient: HttpClient) { }
  currentCode;
  setCurrentCode(code){
    this.currentCode = code;
  }
  getCurrentCode(){
    return this.currentCode;
  }
}
```

And I have a JavaScript file.

where I need to get value from the above typescript file.

Actually I need to get value from the `getCurrentCode()` function of above typescript and print it inside a JavaScript file.

So what I need to write inside my **b.js**  file? how can I import the above file?  Also I need to get value from the above function and write it inside my JavaScript file?

Comment: Why do you need to call angular service from js file?

Comment: @RomanSkydan because I am sending mail to user, so I need to send mail using Node.js . But I have to  get verification code from typescript (angular) . Btw I could generate code using javascript too, but I need to send user's email address from typescript to javascript.

Comment: as javascript is typescript -> just send from typecript to typescript? your issue is not js or ts it is the module type: CommonJS, AMD, UMD, etc

Comment: @Estradiaz I am actually using nodemailer to send mail to user, since nodemailer doesnt run in angular(ts) i have to go to node.js backend. but now  I need to send user email input from angular (.ts) to node.js (.js) .  I am forced to it.

Comment: ok let me rephrase it: nodemailer does not run in the browser, where your angular app runs. thus you have to seperate those application and now you wonder what is the most efficient way to let a client comunicate via http with a server?

Comment: @Estradiaz yes kind of it . client (angular - ts) has to send his email address to server (nodemailer - js)  , so that server can send a code to his email

Comment: Ok - first get rid of js and ts thoughtprocess and then write an interface eg: rest api to transport your infos to your backend and in there execute your `transporter.sendmail`, e.g. express

Comment: I didn't know and tried importing nodemailer to ts (and wanted to do the .ts -> .ts data transfer), but app crashed, later I have known, its not possible to have nodemailer in .ts https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62878886/angular-nodemailer-shows-a-lot-of-runtime-error

Comment: @Estradiaz ok i will try the api method, thanks for your suggestion

Comment: it is possible in ts - it is not possible in **browser**!

Answer (score 0):

On Node, you can just `require` what you need from the Typescript file in the usual way. Basically you can think of the Typescript file as Javascript, the two are completely interoperable, it's just that you need to transpile it to JS using `tsc` before it will run on Node.

For example, in your JS file, you can just do something like the following

```
// Note, this assumes you've transpiled a.component.ts
// to a file called a.component.js (in the same directory)
const { DataService } = require('./a.component') 

const myDataService = new DataService(...)
```

Comment: can you give me an exapmple?

Comment: Sure, added an example. Just using `require` works exactly as if `a.component.ts` were a javascript file.

Comment: I have tried. it says : "cannot import outside module" [ i did tsc file.ts before importing, but didnt't work]

Comment: How do you write this in import.. format? I want to import a function from a typescript file and use the returned value from it.